# Eclipse RCP Project Unable to Reference Regular Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

#### Question

I have three projects that I am working with in Eclipse in the same workspace: one RCP application, and two pure Java projects that it depends on. The one Java project depends on the other; this is accomplished in Properties->Java Build Path->Projects. However, neither that nor any other of the numerous methods I have tried have worked to make the RCP project depend on the pure Java projects. The solution I have now is haphazard; I have added the source of the other two projects to the RCP project as linked source folders. Is there a better solution?

#### Similar StackOverflow Questions

This question is similar to [How to set up project references Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571905/how-to-set-up-project-references-eclipse) and [Java Web Project referencing another Java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691553/java-web-project-referencing-another-java-project), but their answers did not fix my problems. It is even more similar to [Eclipse RCP with project dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185339/eclipse-rcp-with-project-dependency), but the solution offered there is precisely what I do not want to do (convert the plain Java projects to plugin projects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not want to convert them to plugin projects? It's nothing more than some additions in the MANIFEST.MF file. (unless you want to manually load classes, then it's more complicated)

Comment: It also creates a `build.properties` file, incidentally. The reason why I wanted to avoid it was because I didn't want libraries that didn't need to depend on RCP depend on it.

Comment: How does this sound: create 2 extra OSGi Bundle/Plugin projects that simply contain the JAR of the library; wire your build script to create the JARs and copy them to their respective locations; finally set up the plugins to only have the embedded library but no sources.